# Lagrangian FOC without lambda?

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

When I use the Lagrange method, how do I know when the multiplier wont be one of the FOC's?

In my Economics textbook (Varian), the author sometimes doesn't use dL/dLambda (=0) as one of the FOC's. I dont get why?

In my attached example, why dont the FOC's become

dL/dx1 = 0

dL/dG = 0

dL/dLambda = 0

dL/dMu = 0

Example without lambda:

[image: Example without lambda]

Thanks for input!

Comment: What does "FOC" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOC stands for First-Order Condition. FOCs are necessary conditions derived from first derivatives in constrained  maximization/minimization problems. Consider for example the problem

$$\max f(x) \quad s.t. \quad g(x)=0$$

where  $f\colon \mathbb {R} ^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb {R} $ is the objective function, and $\displaystyle g\colon \mathbb {R} ^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb {R} $ is the constraint function.

Under some regularity conditions, the  [Lagrange Multipliers Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier#Statement) tells us that a necessary condition for a point $x^*$ to be a solution of the above problem is that there exists some $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ such that

$$\nabla f(x^*)=\lambda\nabla g(x^*)$$

where $\nabla$ denotes the gradient.

In economics textbooks this is usually done by defining the Lagrangian function

$$\mathcal L(x,\lambda):=f(x)-\lambda g(x)$$

so that the previous FOC can be written as $\nabla_x \mathcal L(x^*,\lambda) =0$.

Now, the constraint condition $g(x^*)=0$ is obviously also a necessary condition, and setting the derivative of the Lagrangian w.r.t. $\lambda$ equal to zero gives precisely this constraint condition.

So the bottom line is that the derivative of $\mathcal L(x,\lambda)$ w.r.t. $\lambda$ doesn't give you any additional information, since we already know that the constraint must be satisfied at the optimum. (although this condition is often used with the other FOCs when solving for $x^*$).

Comment: Thanks Alphie. Thats exactly the input I needed. It becomes unnecessary to derive w.r.t. the multipliers because you need the derivative of the inner functions to get the MRS and MC given optimality condition: MRS1 + MRS2 = MC.

Comment: @JohannaW Glad to be of help. Please consider upvoting and accepting this answer if you are statisfied.

Comment: Yeah I voted but it says I nees 15 reputation to cast a vote. =)

Comment: OK then I believe you can accept the answer